# Write from compute shader to persistently mapped SSBO fails

Tags: scala, opengl, lwjgl, opengl-4

I'm trying to write to a SSBO with a compute shader and read the data back on the cpu.

The compute shader is just a 1x1x1 toy example that writes 24 floats:

```c
#version 450 core

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout (std430, binding = 0) buffer particles {
    float Particle[];
};

void main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i) {
        Particle[i] = i + 1;
    }
}
```

This is how I run the shader and read the data:

```scala
val bufferFlags = GL_MAP_READ_BIT | GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT | GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT
val bufferSize = 24 * 4
val bufferId = glCreateBuffers()

glNamedBufferStorage(bufferId, bufferSize, bufferFlags)

val mappedBuffer = glMapNamedBufferRange(bufferId, 0, bufferSize, bufferFlags)

mappedBuffer.rewind()
val mappedFloatBuffer = mappedBuffer.asFloatBuffer()

mappedFloatBuffer.rewind()

val ssboIndex = glGetProgramResourceIndex(progId, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, "particles")

val props = Array(GL_BUFFER_BINDING)
val params = Array(-1)
glGetProgramResourceiv(progId, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, ssboIndex, props, null, params)

glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, params(0), bufferId)

glUseProgram(progId)

val sync = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0)
glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1)

glClientWaitSync(sync, 0, 1000000000) match {
  case GL_TIMEOUT_EXPIRED =>
    println("Timeout expired")

  case GL_WAIT_FAILED =>
    println("Wait failed. " + glGetError())

  case _ =>
    println("Result:")

    while(mappedFloatBuffer.hasRemaining) {
      println(mappedFloatBuffer.get())
    }
}
```

I expect it to print the numbers 1 to 24 but instead it prints 24 zeros. Using the cpu I can read and write (if the `GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT` is set) to the buffer just fine. The same happens if I don't use DSA (`glBindBuffer` / `glBufferStorage` / `glMapBufferRange` instead). However, if the buffer isn't mapped while the shader runs and I only map it just before printing the contents, everything works correctly. Isn't this exactly what persistently mapped buffers are for? So I can keep it mapped while the gpu is using it?

I checked for any errors, with `glGetError` as well as with the newer debug output but I don't get any.

[Here (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/pVqU8uCb) is a fully working example. You need [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org) to run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your code.

First, you put the fence sync before the command you want to sync with. Syncing with a fence syncs with all commands executed *before* the fence, not after. If you want to sync with the compute shader execution, then you have to insert the fence after the dispatch call, not before.

Second, synchronization is not enough. Writes to an SSBO are incoherent, so you must follow the rules of [incoherent memory accesses](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Incoherent_Memory_Access) in order to make them visible to you. In this case, you need to insert an appropriate memory barrier between the compute operation and when you try to read from the buffer with `glMemoryBarrier`. Since you're reading the data via mapping, the proper barrier to use is `GL_CLIENT_MAPPED_BUFFER_BARRIER_BIT`.

Your code appears to work when you use non-persistent mapping, but this is mere appearance. It's still undefined behavior due to the improper incoherent memory access (ie: the lack of a memory barrier). It just so happens that the UB does what you want... in that case.

Comment: In hindsight it's so obvious. Anyways, thanks for pointing it out. However, I don't think the memory barrier is necessary since the buffer is mapped with  `GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT`.

Comment: @IchBinKeinBaum: Yes, it is necessary. The coherent bit is about whether you need to flush/invalidate the buffer in order for the GPU to see what you wrote/in order for you to see what the GPU wrote. You still need to ensure that the caches used by the compute shader have been cleared, so that the writes from the CS are actually in GPU memory. That's what the barrier is for.

Comment: [The docs](http://docs.gl/gl4/glBufferStorage) specifically say "If GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT is set and the server does a write, the app must call FenceSync with GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE (or glFinish). Then the CPU will see the writes after the sync is complete." There should not be a need for a memory barrier.